# Text in graphicsView in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating an application in Qt in which I can add different entities in graphics view on click of a button. I want that user can add text in graphics view when he clicks the push button for same. How can I make use of QGraphicsTextItem to do so?
I have different buttons in my application like for drawing line, circle in which user specifies the points for doing so. Similarly I have a button to add text. I have seen we can have the implementation of adding text in graphics view as :

addText("hello")

This text is already defined. I want that text should be entered at run time, it should not be statically or predefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you give is quite sparse. From what it sounds like, you should be able to get the `QTextDocument` associated with the `QGraphicsTextItem` by calling `QGraphicsTextItem::document ()`. If you don't want to do anything fancy, you should be able to set/replace the text of the item by calling `QTextDocument::setPlainText ( const QString & text )`. If you want to prompt the user to enter text, you can use the static `QInputDialog::getText` method to get a single `QString` from the user.

Does this help? If this doesn't match your use case you might need to provide a bit more context.

Edit: posting a minimal example on how you can place text in a QGraphicsView/Scene. You click the mouse button in a particular location, it will ask you to enter text and then put the text where the mouse click happened. Does this help?

Edit 2: adding a more complete yet still dummy example below the first one showing creation of a mainwindow with a custom widget and a dummy button to toggle on/off text insertion. Note that this is certainly not production ready code, it should show the working principle and was not optimized or beautified in any way.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QInputDialog>

class MyGraphicsView: public QGraphicsView
{
public:
  MyGraphicsView( QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent = 0) : QGraphicsView(scene,parent) {}

public slots:
  void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event );



};

void MyGraphicsView::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
{
  const QPoint &pos = event->pos();

  bool ok;
  QString text = QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("QInputDialog::getText()"),
                                   tr("Please enter your text"), QLineEdit::Normal,
                                   "Replace with your text", &ok);

  if (!ok || text.isEmpty()) return;

  QGraphicsTextItem *textItem = this->scene()->addText(text);
  textItem->setPos(mapToScene(pos));

}


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    scene.setSceneRect( -100.0, -100.0, 200.0, 200.0 );

    MyGraphicsView view( &scene );
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**'Complete' Example**

**mainwindow.ui** (created with qt designer)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="MyGraphicsView" name="graphicsView"/>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QToolButton" name="toolButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Add Text</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>27</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MyGraphicsView</class>
   <extends>QGraphicsView</extends>
   <header location="global">mygraphicsview.h</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MYMAINWINDOW_H
#define MYMAINWINDOW_H

#include "mygraphicsview.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore>

class MyMainWindow: public QMainWindow, private Ui::MainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
 public:
  MyMainWindow( QWidget *parent = 0 );

  public slots:
  void on_toolButton_clicked( bool checked ) { graphicsView->setAddText(checked); }


};

#endif // MYMAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow( QWidget * ) {
  setupUi(this);
  QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
  scene->setSceneRect( -100.0, -100.0, 200.0, 200.0 );
  toolButton->setCheckable(true);
  graphicsView->setScene(scene);

}
```

**mygraphicsview.h**

```
#ifndef MYGRAPHICSVIEW_H
#define MYGRAPHICSVIEW_H

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

class MyGraphicsView: public QGraphicsView
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MyGraphicsView( QWidget *parent = 0) : QGraphicsView(parent), addText(false) {}
  void setAddText(bool state) {addText = state;}
  public slots:
  void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event );

 private:
  bool addText;

};

#endif // MYGRAPHICSVIEW_H
```

**mygraphicsview.cpp**

```
#include "mygraphicsview.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>




void MyGraphicsView::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
{
  if( ! addText) return;

  const QPoint &pos = event->pos();
  bool ok;
  QString text = QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("QInputDialog::getText()"),
                                   tr("Please enter your text"), QLineEdit::Normal,
                                   "Replace with your text", &ok);

  if ( !ok || text.isEmpty()) return;

  QGraphicsTextItem *textItem = this->scene()->addText(text);
  textItem->setPos(mapToScene(pos));

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "mygraphicsview.h"
#include <QApplication>


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyMainWindow m;
    m.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope that I have provided you with all the possible information now.

Comment: Do you need the text to appear in a particular location? E.g. at the current position of the mouse?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want at the current position of mouse only.

Comment: @user3877872 I added an example how to do something along the lines of what you described

Comment: I am getting the following error:'MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsScene**)'
     MyGraphicsView view(&scene);

Comment: sorry, that doesn't really give away the actual error. Can you post a bit more of the message that you are getting?

Comment: OOPs My Bad!I copied the half error. It shows no matching function for call to 'MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsScene**)'
     MyGraphicsView view(&scene);
                               ^

Comment: I guess you are declaring your `QGraphicsScene` as `  QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;` or something like that. In that case you only need to do `  MyGraphicsView view( scene );` i.e. give it the pointer. If you declare the straight object like this `QGraphicsScene scene;` then you need to give its address to the `QGraphicsView` like this: `MyGraphicsView view( &scene );`. Does this help?

Comment: I have declared like this only. In the main function: QGraphicsScene scene;
   
MyGraphicsView view( scene )

Comment: wait. Now I am confused. You say you declare `QGraphicsScene scene; MyGraphicsView view( scene )` but your error message says: `no matching function for call to 'MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsScene**)' MyGraphicsView view(&scene);`, that doesn't fit together. The error message I can reproduce when doing what I described `QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;` and then `MyGraphicsView view( &scene );` when verbatim taking the example I posted.

Comment: Even I am confused! I have preceeded exactly as suggested by you

Comment: that seems odd. When I take the code I posted (adding a missing `#include <QGraphicsTextItem>`) I can go to a fresh directory, put all of the code into a single file and do: `qmake -project; qmake; make` and I don't get any error during compilation.

Comment: there are a number of problems with the code you show. You are defining the same class twice to name just one: `class MyGraphicsView: public QGraphicsView` in line 28 and then `class MyGraphicsView : public QMainWindow` in line 83. As line 83 is from mygraphicsview.h this is the one that the compiler will try to use as this file is included in your main.cpp. The second class definition is in the .cpp file so while it will be compiled, but it is not the one that you are using. The graphicsview should inherit from `QGraphicsView`, not `QMainWindow` and then you can embed it into a QMainWindow.

Comment: @user3877872 I edited my answer yet again and added another, more complete example.

Comment: The example worked when I made a separate project. When I am trying to embed in my application. I have added the graphics view through ui and did this way: graphicsView->setAddText(checked); and it says it has no method setAddText. I have also declared it:(

Comment: Add what to do if I want to have multi line text

Comment: For your first post: it is impossible to say what the problem is without the code. Also, this comment thread is getting somewhat longish, maybe eventually you should consider asking a new question.

Comment: For your second post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244859/multiline-qinputdialog-prompt or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625343/qinputdialog-with-multiline-text should be of help

Comment: Sorry for commenting here,I know this thread has been too long.But I have a question regarding the code.I din't get one thing that what property of toolbutton or what allow the button to remain activated until it is pressed again and what is allowing it to add the text multiple no. of times until we press the button again. I want this the same for other buttons too in which on click of a button line is painted in graphics view, I want this to happen multiple no of times until and unless the button is pressed again.I commented out the things to find the reason but couldn't.Kindly help

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `setCheckable ( bool )`. This basically makes the button behave like a checkbox, i.e. you set it as active and only when you click again the state gets reverted. The signal to watch is `toggled` with the current check state as argument, see also http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#toggled

Comment: Does that also allows to repeat the event again and again? If I wish to paint the graphicsitems mutiple times without having the need to push the buttoon again, will that help?