# How to update Graphics View in a Qt Widgets Project(Qt Creator)

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have created a Qt Widgets Application using Qt Creator(Windows 7, MinGW).

I have added a GraphicsView (named as `graphicsView`) and a push button (named as `pbClick`).

The `on_pbClick_clicked()` function is given below:

```
void MainWindow::on_pbClick_clicked()
{
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    //adding some text to the scene
    scene.addText("Hello, world!", QFont("Times", 20, QFont::Bold));
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(&scene);
    ui->graphicsView->show();
}
```

When I click the `pbClick` button, nothing happens within the `graphicsView`.

How can I make the "Hello, world!" text be shown inside the `graphicsView`.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961013/text-in-graphicsview-in-qt

Comment: @ArunPrasanth The question you are linking is answering a different qn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create your scene on stack, it is a problem, try to create it on heap (use pointers) in this case if there are not any mistakes, all should works fine. As doc said:

> The view does not take ownership of scene.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#setScene

It means that when you create scene on stack, this scene will be deleted "in the end" of `on_pbClick_clicked` slot. So your scene does not exist anymore, and you can't see nothing.

```
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    //adding some text to the scene
    scene->addText("Hello, world!", QFont("Times", 20, QFont::Bold));
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->show();
```